# Why is the WindowsError while deleting the temporary file?

Tags: python, temporary-files

1. I have created a temporary file.
2. Added some data to the file created.
3. Saved it and then trying to delete it.

But I am getting `WindowsError`. I have closed the file after editing it. How do I check which other process is accessing the file.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67517, Dec  4 2008, 16:51:00) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tempfile
>>> __, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> print filename
c:\docume~1\admini~1\locals~1\temp\tmpm5clkb
>>> fptr = open(filename, "wb")
>>> fptr.write("Hello World!")
>>> fptr.close()
>>> import os
>>> os.remove(filename)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
       another process: 'c:\\docume~1\\admini~1\\locals~1\\temp\\tmpm5clkb'
```

Comment: 8 questions, several with obviously correct answers, and 0 accepted answers--just how long do you expect people to keep answering you?

Comment: Oops.. I did not realized there is accept button. I will accept answers which I feel are correct..Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp):

> mkstemp() returns a tuple containing an OS-level handle to an open file (as would be returned by os.open()) and the absolute pathname of that file, in that order. New in version 2.3.

So, `mkstemp` returns both the OS file handle to *and* the filename of the temporary file. When you re-open the temp file, the original returned file handle is still open (no-one stops you from opening twice or more the same file in your program).

If you want to operate on that OS file handle as a python file object, you can:

```
>>> __, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> fptr= os.fdopen(__)
```

and then continue with your normal code.

Answer (score 7):

The file is still open. Do this:

```
fh, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
...
os.close(fh)
os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: @Vijayendra Bapte, there are file descriptor operations in the os module that you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to release the fptr to close the file cleanly. Try setting fptr to None.