# os.remove() in windows gives "[Error 32] being used by another process"

Tags: python, windows

I know this question has been asked before quiet a lot on SO and elsewhere too. I still couldn't get it done. And im sorry if my English is bad

Removing file in linux was much more simpler. Just `os.remove(my_file)` did the job, But in windows it gives

```
    os.remove(my_file)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: (file-name)
```

***my code :***

```
line_count = open(my_file, mode='r')        #
t_lines = len(line_count.readlines())       # For total no of lines
outfile = open(dec_file, mode='w')
with open(my_file, mode='r') as contents:
    p_line = 1
    line_infile = contents.readline()[4:]
    while line_infile:
        dec_of_line = baseconvert(line_infile.rstrip(),base16,base10)
        if p_line == t_lines:
            dec_of_line += str(len(line_infile)).zfill(2)
            outfile.write(dec_of_line + "\r\n")
        else:
            outfile.write(dec_of_line + "\r\n")
        p_line += 1
        line_infile = contents.readline()[4:]
outfile.close()
os.remove(my_file)
```

Here `my_file` is a variable that contains complete path structure of a file. Like wise `dec_file` also contains path, but to a new file. And the file im trying to remove is the file that's being used under `read mode`. Need some help please.

***my try's :***

1. Tried closing the file `my_file.close()`. The corresponding error i got was `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'`. I knew, when a file is in
   `read mode` it automatically closes when it comes to the end of the
   file. But still i gave it a try
2. Also tried by `os.close(my_file)` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470388/3869739. i got error as `TypeError: an integer is required`
3. Or, am i getting this error just because i have opened the file
   twice (for counting the line and to read the file content),..?

Comment: code look fine, what is written inside with statement i.e. in do somthing ??

Comment: @VivekSable ,..I edited the code,.. this is my complete code. It dose a baseconversion from a file and paste it inside another file.

Comment: @eryksun ,. i didn't get what you mentioned,.. can you please explain `"Just use the single contents file object in the with statement"`.

Comment: @eryksun ,. It Worked,.. Thanks a lot,.. Now how should i select/accept this as an answer,..? Will you make a separate answer,..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pythonic way of reading from or writing to a file is by using a `with` context.

To read a file:

```
with open("/path/to/file") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    #Inside the block, the file is still open

# Outside `with` here, f.close() is automatically called.
```

To write:

```
with open("/path/to/file", "w") as f:
    print>>f, "Goodbye world"

# Outside `with` here, f.close() is automatically called.
```

---

Now, if there's no other process reading or writing to the file, and assuming you have all the permission you should be able to close the file. **There is a very good chance that there's a resource leak (file handle not being closed), because of which Windows will not allow you to delete a file**. Solution is to use `with`.

---

Further, to clarify on few other points:

- Its the garbage collector that causes the closure of the stream when the object is destroyed. The file is not auto-closed upon complete reading. That wouldn't make sense if the programmer wanted to rewind, would it?
- os.close(..) internally calls the C-API `close(..)` that takes an integer file descriptor. Not string as you passed.

Comment: I used the with statements as you said,.. 
 `with open(dec_file, mode='w') as outfile, open(my_file, mode='r') as contents:` and the `do something` followed with `os.remove(my_file)`

I still get the same `[Error 32]`

Comment: That means there's a file really open elsewhere. 1) Are you able to delete from a terminal ? 2) Are you able to delete it from another python script that does not open the file at all ?

Comment: You've opened the file twice (first and fourth lines) so presumably you need to close it twice.  If the `with` automatically closes that instance, you just need a `line_count.close()` to close the other one.