# Rename txt file. Edited version: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-rename, windowserror

I'm working with python 2.7x. I'm quite new to python and will really appreciate your help. I have read many posts including those shown below to name a few about this error:

[WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'new.dat'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322932/windowserror-error-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being) --> my file close instruction is at the end already.

[python 2 [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130958/python-2-error-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used) --> I can't use shutil as there's some error in the python program I'm using and I cant edit the pathway as my computer is adminstrative protected.

[Rename Files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-files-in-python) -->After following the suggestion, I got NameError: name 'rename' is not defined instead... :/

etc etc.

After trying to rectify my codes, I'm still getting the same error.

What I would like to do is: I read the files in a directory, if any of the files contains a specific string, I would rename the text file 
(i.e. first.txt to firstfound.txt.)

EDITED VERSION:
I tried moving the abc.close() before I rename the file:

```
import os

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
#fill in file directory here
abc = open(fname)
for line in abc:
 if not line.find("scramble") : 
  continue
 oldfile = fname
abc.close() 
if oldfile == fname:
 for title in fname:
    endname = title.find('.txt')
    oldtitle = title[:endname]
    newfile = oldtitle +"found.txt"
    os.rename(oldfile,newfile)
```

But I have this error instead for the last line.
os.rename(oldfile,newfile)
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists. There's no file with the new name in my folder.
Thanks so much for your advice!

EDITED VERSION 2: I have also tried this other set of codes but it gave me WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied. May I know if there's such a thing that  I cannot rename the txt file because I have no administrator privilege? Thank you!

```
import os

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
#fill in file directory here
abc = open(fname)
for line in abc:
 if not line.find("scramble") : 
  continue
 oldfile = fname
abc.close() 

if (oldfile == fname): #+'/' +  "a.txt"
 for title in fname:
    endname = title.find('.txt')
    oldtitle = title[:endname]
    new_file = oldtitle +'/' +  "a.txt"
    os.rename(fname,new_file)
```

INITIAL version: The error I got is at the os.rename line. "WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

My whole program code is as shown below:

```
import os

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
#fill in file directory here
abc = open(fname)
for line in abc:
 if not line.find("scramble") : 
  continue
 old_file = fname
 for title in fname:
    endname = title.find('.txt')
    oldtitle = title[:endname]
    new_file = oldtitle +'/' +  "found.txt"
    os.rename(old_file,new_file) ##WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
abc.close()
```

I don't understand why this error persists. (I have closed all the files & folders). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to your open() call in your code.  The open() function in python opens file file for reading/writing, so if you open a file then you cannot call rename on it as it is open in another location.

Instead you should call

```
abc.close()
```

before renaming your file.

See [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for more information regarding file I/O.

Comment: It's either this or some other process is accessing your file.

Comment: I tried to put abc.close() before the sentence " for title in fname:", but I got error instead: ""for line in abc:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file ""

Comment: Any idea what could be the other processes?
@PrajjwalSrivastav

Comment: @bennerv I re-tried closing before I rename (the codes are on the main post under EDITED version). However, now they have a new error 183: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. I'm pretty sure there's no file name similar to the new file. I have searched on the search engine for similar posts but to no avail. :/